# How to intercept program execution or document opening

Tags: windows

I need to develop an application, service, or whatever, that intercepts a program execution before it is actually run.

For instance, this is what I need to accomplish.

1. User double clicks or opens an EXE file in Windows 7 or Windows 10
2. My application or service is run, validating the user can run that application depending on some settings stored wherever
3. If user is allowed to run that application, the application is run. Ortherwise, an error is shown and the application is not run.

On the other hand, I need to do the same for documents.

1. User tries to open some document (txt, doc, xls, etc) using the associated application.
2. My application or service is run, validating the user can open that document depending on some settings stored wherever
3. If user is allowed to open that document, the document is opened. Ortherwise, an access denied error is shown.

Can you give me a start point to do this, please? I am a C++ and C# developer

I know that Windows already provide something like that, but I need to do user authentication using a fingerprint reader I own.

Comment: What is wrong with user access permissions already present in Windows operating system that already behave like you describe?

Comment: So for each of those actions, your program should intercept that and the user must read their fingerprint again? Why don't you use the fingerprint reader as login method, and tune down the permissions for that user? If you really want to go the hard way and spend a lot of hours reinventing the wheel, you could implement a filesystem filter driver. But you really don't want to.

Comment: That is a customer requirements. Login provider is also considered, but when inside Windows, customer wants the fingerprint mechanism, not only for authenticated user.